# How to arrange carboxylic acids (phenylacetic acid and acetic acid) by increasing acidity?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

> Why is $\ce{Ph-CH2-COOH}$ more acidic than $\ce{CH3COOH}$ although the equilibrium of ionization lies mainly backward for both of them?

Attempt:

In the ionized form of $\ce{Ph-CH2-COOH}$ we have a $\ce{Ph-CH2}$-group donating its electron to carbonyl carbon while in case of acetic acid we have a methyl group donating its electron to the carbonyl carbon.

But which one of them is stabilized more?

Answer (score 7):

The $\mathrm pK_\mathrm a$ difference between phenylacetic acid and acetic acid is around 0.5 and the trends become more obvious when other arylalkanoic acids are included in the comparison. Numbers in red are the $\mathrm pK_\mathrm a$ values.

[image: arylalkanoic acids]

1. Apparently, phenylacetic acid is a stronger acid than acetic acid. Adding a further phenyl subsituent even increases the acid strength.
2. The effect levels off with the distance of the phenyl substituent and the carboxylate. Note that 4-phenylbutyric acid is just as strong as acetic acid. It's as if there isn't any phenyl group at all.

**Would you think that there is a $-I$ effect of the phenyl substituent on the $\ce{-COOH}$ group?**

Comment: Phenyl ring is supposed to exert +I effect on carbonyl group